# How does Image Size validator work?

Tags: content-editor, validation

I wanted to set image size validation for an image field for example the image field should not accept any image more than 2 mb. For this I tried using Image Size validator available in Sitecore.

Item Path:

> /sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/System/Image
>   Size

The parameter field was set to `"maxSize = 2MB"`
But this is not working. 
How to make use of this validator to validate image size?
How to set the parameter field value?

[image]

Comment: finally, at the end how did you approach it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decompile the code of : **Sitecore.Data.Validators.FieldValidators.ImageSizeValidator** and I see in the validator is verifing if the size of the image field is bigger then value of MaxSizeinMemory and MaxSizeInDatabase settings. These 2 are stored in the Sitecore.config file.

```
   <!--  MEDIA - MAX SIZE IN DATABASE
        The maximum allowed size of media intended to be stored in a database (binary blob).
        This value must be less than the ASP.NET httpRuntime.maxRequestLength setting.
        Default value: 500MB
  -->
<setting name="Media.MaxSizeInDatabase" value="500MB" />

and 

 <!--  MEDIA - MAX SIZE IN MEMORY
        The maximum size of media to load into memory for processing (resizing etc.).
        Default value: 40MB
  -->
<setting name="Media.MaxSizeInMemory" value="40MB" />
```

Here is the code which is validating the size of image.

```
if (size > Settings.Media.MaxSizeInMemory)
        {
            base.Text = this.GetText("The image referenced in the Image field \"{0}\" is too big to be resized.", new string[]
            {
                field.DisplayName
            });
            return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Warning);
        }
        if (size > Settings.Media.MaxSizeInDatabase)
        {
            base.Text = Translate.Text("The image referenced in the Image field \"{0}\" is too big to be stored in the database.", new object[]
            {
                field.DisplayName
            });
            return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Warning);
        }
```

To test this validator you need to change that values to a lower value or add an image which is bigger than 40 MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding a way to `create a custom validation rule in Sitecore to handle this on a specific image field on a template` then you can consider my brief answer in a dedicated blog **[here](https://dev.to/tsaxena4k/custom-image-size-limiter-media-type-checker-in-sitecore-3809)**. The Ask or the Task to achieve is listed below - the solution for which I have provided in the blog itself.

## Ask

The requirement was to limit image size on a image field in any template and also to restrict the type of image.

For example: **The image should be less then 1 MB & should be either png or jpg**.